# Does asyncio.as_completed yield Futures or coroutines?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

From the `asyncio` [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.as_completed):

> `asyncio.as_completed(aws, *, loop=None, timeout=None)`
>
> Run awaitable objects in the aws set concurrently. **Return an iterator
>   of Future objects.** Each Future object returned represents the earliest
>   result from the set of the remaining awaitables.

I would assume each of these `Future` objects has the methods described in [`asyncio.Future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.Future): `.cancelled()`, `.exception()`, and `.result()`.  But it appears that the yielded elements are just coroutines, not `Future` objects.  What am I missing?

This seems to defeat the description of `.as_completed()`.  How is the coroutine "completed" if I need to `await` it?

```
>>> import asyncio
>>> import aiohttp
>>> 
>>> async def get(session, url):
...     async with session.request('GET', url) as resp:
...         t = await resp.text()
...         return t
... 
>>> async def bulk_as_completed(urls):
...     async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
...         aws = [get(session, url) for url in urls]
...         for future in asyncio.as_completed(aws):
...             for i in ('cancelled', 'exception', 'result'):
...                 print(hasattr(future, i))
...             print(type(future))
...             try:
...                 result = await future
...             except:
...                 pass
...             else:
...                 print(type(result))
...                 print()
... 
>>> 
>>> urls = (
...     'https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html',
...     'https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html',
...     'https://docs.python.org/3/library/this-page-will-404.html',
... )
>>> 
>>> asyncio.run(bulk_as_completed(urls))
False
False
False
<class 'coroutine'>
<class 'str'>

False
False
False
<class 'coroutine'>
<class 'str'>

False
False
False
<class 'coroutine'>
<class 'str'>
```

---

Ultimately, the reason I care about this is because I'd like to **let exceptions bubble up as they do in `asyncio.gather(..., return_exceptions=True)`.**  Consider adding on one bogus URL that will raise when `session.request()` is called:

```
urls = (
    'https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html',
    'https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html',
    'https://docs.python.org/3/library/this-page-will-404.html',

    # This URL will raise on session.request().  How can I propagate
    # that exception to the iterator of results?
    'https://asdfasdfasdf-does-not-exist-asdfasdfasdf.com'
)
```

What I would *like* to be able to do is something like this (using the methods of a Future object, but these aren't Future objects at all, which is the problem):

```
async def bulk_as_completed(urls):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        aws = [get(session, url) for url in urls]
        for future in asyncio.as_completed(aws):
            if future.cancelled():
                res = futures.CancelledError()
            else:
                exc = future.exception()
                if exc is not None:
                    res = exc
                else:
                    res = future.result()
            # ...
            # [Do something with `res`]
```

Comment: This question is really strange as it seems the doc is wrong at all: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/dce345c51abd5081679a487315fb47efddc54cdb/Lib/asyncio/tasks.py#L526. According to source code, it does not return a Future.

Comment: Yes @Sraw, it looks like the docstring itself says coroutines, while the docs say Futures.  I wonder if this changed in a certain minor version of Python 3.x

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What I would like to be able to do is something like this [...]

Perhaps not as convenient, but you should be able to extract the exception with code like this:

```
async def bulk_as_completed(urls):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        aws = [get(session, url) for url in urls]
        for future in asyncio.as_completed(aws):
            try:
                res = await future
            except Exception as e:
                res = e
            # ...
            # [Do something with `res`]
```

> This [yielding coroutines rather than futures] seems to defeat the description of `.as_completed()`. How is the coroutine "completed" if I need to await it?

It's not. When `asyncio.as_completed` was first implemented, asynchronous iterators didn't exist. Without asynchronous iteration there was no way to return the futures as they complete, so `as_completed` sort of faked it by yielding (immediately) dummy awaitables which one has to await to get the actual result.

Even if `as_completed` yielded actual futures, it wouldn't help with your use case because those futures wouldn't complete without someone awaiting them. To provide the expected semantics of `as_completed` yielding *completed* futures, `as_completed` needs to implement asynchronous iteration, whose equivalent of `__next__` can await.

The surprising behavior of `as_completed` has been brought up before, and I have already filed [an issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue33533) to fix it by providing async iteration. Once it is implemented, your original code will work with just the `for` changed to `async for`.

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing and then did not edit my question.  But thank you, especially for the explanation.

Comment: The only difference, it seems, is that there is no concept of `.cancelled()` when the iterator contains coroutines rather than Futures.  But I suppose that's null and void and the behavior is what it is.

Comment: @BradSolomon The current `as_completed` could easily yield futures by wrapping the coroutines into tasks. But that wouldn't buy anything because the futures wouldn't be _completed_, you'd still have to await them - and handle exeptions, etc.